# Launching GIMP... Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag

Tags: python, utf-8, fontconfig

I am running a python 3.5 application called Ortho4XP which, among other things, calls for Gimp at a certain stage; when it tries to launch Gimp I get the warning above and the script freeezes. My machine is osx El Capitan
Searching stackoverflow I find similar questions and it is suggested to unchek "Select locale varoables on startup" but if I do this other problems appear and the script does not run at all.

José

Comment: Select locale from `locale -a`. Run: `export LANG=<my_chosen_locale>`. Run `locale` to check for errors

Comment: Replying to ANSWER 1 I posted the result of issuing command locale. I don't know what my chosen locale should be and I don't know the syntax; my OS language is English.

Comment: `locale -a` (note the `a`), shows you all the installed locales. You need to choose one appropriate for you, based on your prefered language, region and encoding. For example, I use `en_GB.UTF-8`. If you're on OS X your locale should already be `something.UTF-8`. If not, then you've broken something in your shell environment

Comment: OK. I set LANG and now issuing locale produces: `LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=` still the problem persists.

Comment: Does your application now work?

Comment: I just checked and it works, in spite of the warning. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set environment locale variables: `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE` and  `LANG`.
You can set these variables with:

```
import os 
os.environ['LANG'] = # desired locale
os.environ['LC_CTYPE'] = # desired locale
os.environ['LC_ALL'] = # desired locale
```

Comment: Issuing a locale command I get this: `LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=`